# Asp.net when i publish my aspx file it's not fully going on server

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, publish, remote-server

my all aspx files working properly on local machine, but when i publish my files to remote server my file's not going fully here's the compare picture of my aspx file.

[image]

[image]

That's why im getting an exception on remote -> *Content ('Y') does not match any properties within a 'X', make sure it is well-formed.*
As you can see i'm stuck here...

## What i did

- I re-published my solution from VS - not worked.
- I uploaded my aspx file from Filezilla - not worked.
- I re-published only this file - not worked.

Any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

I solved it again after hours  and hours....

because of im connected to internet via a VPN when i try to upload my files to FTP it somehow don't go. I don't know why but if i disconnect from VPN everything works as expected.

Thanks anyway.